# Converting to PDF and Excel in a struct array and sending it as a response in Go api

Tags: excel, go, pdf, data-conversion

I am writing an api. I want to be able to download the table as pdf and excel with api. How can I convert a struct array to excel and pdf? Is there a library in Golang like datafram.to_excel , dataframe.to_csv in Python?

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/gocarina/gocsv"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

type Test struct {
    ID     int    `json:"ID"`
    Name   string `json:"Name"`
    Delete string `json:"Delete"`
}

func main() {

    r := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    r.HandleFunc("/a", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

        tests := []*Test{
            {
                ID:     1,
                Name:   "a",
                Delete: "delete",
            },
            {
                ID:     2,
                Name:   "b",
                Delete: "delete",
            },
        }

        gocsv.Marshal(tests, rw)

    }).Methods(http.MethodGet)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", r))
}
```

I found something like this to export csv file. Do you have anything you can recommend for PDF and Excel?

Comment: Your question, as asked, [is off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and will be closed. Please pick a suitable venue for asking such questions from [this list](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki#the-go-community).

Comment: As to the essense of your question, I assume you meant `DataFrame` of Pandas. If I'm correct, I'm not aware of any Go package whcih would match Pandas 1-to-1. On the other hand, your task, as stated, appears to be pretty trivial, and you should probably start with exploring <https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=excel> and <https://pkg.go.dev/search?q=pdf>. (And while we're at it, you do not need CVS to convert your data to Excel and PDF formats.)

Comment: How about just writing the table-to-Excel/PDF endpoint in Python: send it a CSV and use Pandas to get back an Excel or PDF? I'm not sure why @kostix thinks this is trivial; there are only a few open-source/free packages for PDF in Go. Python definitely has an advantage there.

Comment: pdfcpu supports making tables, https://pdfcpu.io/generate/create, but it's not documented. You'll need to dig.